# Artificial Intelligence for Rule Based Filtering with Python

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence

I have an academic project to build an application to determine the "feeling" of consumer toward brands: whether it's positive, negative, or neutral. However, I'm stuck with no idea how to get the sample on how to "read" the English with code. For example:

> Mrs. Darlie buy me an apple :)

Contrast to the following sentence:

> I Liked Darlie so much and it wake me up every early morning

From human common sense, we can notice that the first sentence is about a "human". First person describing the lady named Mrs. Darlie, but in my case I want to focus on getting brand names *only*, which means the first sentence should be dropped, focusing on the second sentence instead. From this sentence, we can determine that it's an object while most likely describing the toothpaste we're using every early morning.

How can I build this "common sense" with Python? (If there's any example in PHP, I could try to convert it into Python) or is there any library available? Alternatively, please suggest some keywords for research.

Comment: Start by googling "Brill Parser"

Comment: What you've posed here is not an "easy" problem. The "easiest" way to deal with said problem is to treat coincidences of words in a statistical, rather than rule-based, way.

Comment: @Mark Baker, Thanks for quick respond! Guess the Brill Tagger, Abney Parser, and Brill Parsing is the exact near keywords for this :) and i got this from web http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/desmedt12a/desmedt12a.pdf which is near enough to the problem, too.

Comment: @Joel Cornett, Yea.. recently i'm thinking about possibilities and Naive Bayes Classification, which is focussing on statistical categorise but it's more suitable for the later step to determine the "feeling". Feeling having a set of fixed vocabularies but the "common sense" has not. it need another method to determine it while few years back i did read some scholar about it but i lost the link and forgot the keywords. However, Glad to have you here and Thanks for your advices :)

Comment: Since you mentioned Naive Bayes, [here](http://assumethat.blogspot.com/2012/10/mini-naive-bayes-spam-filter.html) is a quick and dirty spam filter I wrote in Python.

Comment: @JoelCornett, Thanks and it's really quick & dirt LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Tom De Smedt & Walter Daelemans from CLiPS Computational Linguistics Group, University of Antwerp. They solved my questioned in this [Journal](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/desmedt12a/desmedt12a.pdf) with example & entire source code on [This web page](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern).

The concept of this application is first crawling related sentences from social website or any public websites, then backend linked to the Wordnet.org english database to determine the "type" or "category" of the words from the sentences. Next process it with classification technique. it's AWESOME!!

Thanks for reply. and hope this help others :)